# Setting Price Step for Custom Price Attribute in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, price, layered-navigation

I have created a product attribute of type "Price". I am using this attribute as a filter in the Layered Navigation.

My problem is that this custom price attribute does not follow the settings for the default price attribute under `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Layered Navigation`.

I have set the *Price Navigation Step Calculation* field to "Automatic (equalize product counts)". I need this same setting applied to my custom price attribute (id=product_price).

**How can I set my *custom* price attribute to display price tiers as "Automatic (equalize product counts)" instead of "Automatic (equalize price ranges)" which seems to be the default?**

Comment: Great question - Did you manage a solution?

Comment: @Craig, there has been no solution, yet. I found an extension that allows you to set your own ranges, but not the "equalize product count" option.